# Facing issues with smooth scroll to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing issues where when a user clicks on a link it redirects them to a specific `div` with a specific `id`.

I'm using jQuery for the smooth scroll feature.

The issue is when I'm at the Homepage then I click on the About page it normally scrolls there, when I click back on the About link again the page moves a bit click again and it returns to normal.

You can try it out here (https://saa-d.github.io) And all of the code is here (https://github.com/saa-d/saa-d.github.io)

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: I've tried troubleshooting using Chrome's inspection tool, and I think the problem is with the `.stick` CSS class that's responsible for sticking the navbar using JS. But I am not exactly sure what's the issue and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you attach and detach the nav which causes the section to shift up and down by the height of the nav.

To avoid it use `position:absolute` on the nav:

```
nav {
    background-color: #595241;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```